# Where would this question about data pipelines belong?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The question is: "How do I move the logs data in Logstash to AWS Redshift?"

I am looking for existing pipelines or a pipeline like [Luigi](http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/stable/); and their implementation.

I have googled for solutions, but unfortunately, I haven't found any helpful solutions.

So, I wanted to know in which site would this question be on-topic.

---

Edit: I have already asked this [question in the software recs site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25192/pipeline-software-or-frameworks-for-moving-data-from-logstash-to-redshift); but the suggestions which I would get there is about a software/package like Luigi. But, I am looking for an end-to-end solution rather than a dependencies-based package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the face of it, the main question (moving logs) looks like something that would fit [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), as it appears to be a system administration question.

Do consult their [help center](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), to see what is and is not on topic before you ask.

Make sure to include as much pertinent information as possible, including what you have tried, what didn't work and any details that will help others help you.

---

You seem to have come in with a preconceived idea of the solution - why not ask about the actual problem and let the experts inform *you* of the best solution?

Comment: SF would just close the question as it is requesting a product recommendation.